# js async function call (im irritated now)

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, timeout, call

im reading a tutorial on the MSDN. And i encountered an issue about the pub/sub-approach that i could not anderstand yet. Its a statement about the timeout-queue usage in javascript. after trying this code out, im totally confused. on the webpage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404091.aspx

a bit further down is a publish-function, beneath i found this statement:

***"It uses the setInterval function with a timeout of 0 milliseconds to execute the callbacks asynchronously. This allows each subscriber callback to be invoked before the previous callback finishes. This also means callbacks can be invoked before other callbacks have finished. A consequence of asynchronicity is that you cannot predict the order in which callbacks are invoked or finish."***

as far as i know, the function-callbacks are executed in
the order in which they were added to the queue. it doesnt matter which timer is set.

can anyone verify this? or explain me?

the code from the MSDN according to above statement:

```
that.publish = function (eventName, data) {
var context, intervalId, idx = 0;
if (queue[eventName]) {
    intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        if (queue[eventName][idx]) {
            context = queue[eventName][idx].context || this;
            queue[eventName][idx].callback.call(context, data);
            idx += 1;
        } else {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
    }, 0);
}
};
```

Comment: MSDN, not [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)... I think you're right that the callbacks will be executed in order. Regarding "This also means callbacks can be invoked before other callbacks have finished." - Use of the word "finished" implies that other callbacks have "started", i.e., that several callbacks will be executing simultaneously, which won't be true. The callbacks may be queued up, but only one will be executing at a time.

Comment: ok thanx. so its just a misanderstanding